# How do I use json_object in mysql to create objects whose values are dynamic?

Tags: mysql, json

I'm trying to create add a json object to a number of records where the value is a UUID.  poking at it, i can limit the issue to this:

`select json_object("uuid", select UUID())`

even a basic

`select json_object("uuid", select "1")` doesn't seem to work

in both instances i get a syntax error on the subselect.  does json_object not support having one of the parameters be the result of a mysql method?  and/or is there a better way for me to do this?  this is in MySql 5.7.12

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to nest `SELECT`. Just call the function.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT("uuid", UUID());
```